# Mailkit `Sender` from a gmail group alias doesn't work?

Tags: c#, gmail, mailkit, mimekit

I am trying to fix the Sender to a GMAIL group alias but the email is always received from the email alias used in `AuthenticateAsync`

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage() {
    Sender = MailboxAddress.Parse("group@email.com"),
    Subject = subject
};
```

How to correctly set up the `Sender` or `From` so that emails received is from my GMAIL group alias?

Comment: Can you even send from a group from within Gmail?

Comment: No. In order to do that, I need to be able to add an account in GMAIL with that group alias but it complains "Cannot find your Google Account" when trying to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS SES + SNS works like a charm!